# How does Justin Spahr-Summers Macro for safer key-value coding work?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How does Justin Spahr-Summers Macro for safer key-value coding work?

https://gist.github.com/jspahrsummers/1670404

```
#define ObjectKeyPath(OBJECT, KEYPATH) \
    ((void)(NO && ((void)OBJECT.KEYPATH, NO)), @ # KEYPATH )
```

What is the point of / result of this subexpression?

```
(NO && ((void)OBJECT.KEYPATH, NO))
```

and what does this part of the macro do?

```
 @ # KEYPATH
```

Answer (score 1):

`(void)(NO && ((void)OBJECT.KEYPATH, NO))`

Let's work this out, from the inside-out.

`((void)OBJECT.KEYPATH, NO)`

This is an expression using the comma operator, which always returns the last value in the list.  In this case, the last value is `NO`.  The first item in the list translates into an access of the named property.  If the string given as the second operand of the macro is wrong, this will cause a compiler error.

Next, this subexpression is used as the right-hand side of a boolean expression whose first term always evaluates to false.  The reason for this is to silence warnings from the compiler about accessing the getter for its side-effects.  This works because the compiler knows the second half will never execute.

Finally, there is a comma operator used between that first part and the name of the key.

`@ # KEYPATH` constructs a constant `NSString`.

Comment: what does the # do?

Comment: It concatenates 2 strings within a macro.

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons - the # is [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification) not concatenation. It takes the argument token (`KEYPATH`) and wraps it in double quotes - so the final result is `@ "KEYPATH"`, an Obj-C string constant as Avi stated.

Comment: @CRD, thanks for the correction.  Macros were never my thing.